# Ruby - how to multiply variables within a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, methods

I'm using a method to try and multiply two variables as follows -

```
def total_amount
  self.quantity.to_i * self.event.price.to_i
end
```

I'm building an events app using Ruby on Rails and the aim of the method is to allow one user to book multiple spaces for a paid event.

The method simply isn't working as when I click through to make a payment the amount simply shows as 0(zero). The method is in my booking model, in my bookings controller I have the following code -

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(quantity: params[:quantity])
    @booking.user = current_user
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user

    Booking.transaction do
      @event.reload
      if @event.bookings.count > @event.number_of_spaces
        flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "event is fully booked"
      end
    end

    if @booking.save
      # CHARGE THE USER WHO'S BOOKED
      # #{} == puts a variable into a string
      Stripe::Charge.create(
        amount: @event.price_pennies,
        currency: "gbp",
        card: @booking.stripe_token,
        description: "Booking number #{@booking.id}")
      flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
      redirect_to event_path(@event)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Payment unsuccessful"
      render "new"
    end

    if @event.is_free?

      @booking.save!
      flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
      redirect_to event_path(@event)
    end
  end

  private

  def booking_params
      params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :quantity)
  end
end
```

I have an input space on my events.show form which allows the user to input the number of spaces they require. The booking form has the following line of code which should reflect the total amount required -

```
<p>Total Amount<%= @booking.total_amount %></p>
```

I added `.to_i` to both variables as without this I received a NilClass error. How can I amend this so the method creates the correct output?

Comment: `nil.to_i` is zero, so if either of those values is nil the multiplication will return zero.

Comment: On the attempts I used, neither would have been zero. I used 2 for quantity and £1.50 for price. But the output was zero.

Comment: It's probably because of the currency symbol. `'1.50'.to_i` is 1, `'1.50'.to_f` is 1.50, and `'£1.50'.to_i` is 0. This is how ruby string-to-integer conversion works. You should use floats for currency and strip out the `£` before converting

Comment: Is it as simple as just using .to_f then?

Comment: no, because of the `£` sign. If you know for certain the first character of the string will be `£`, you can just do `string[1..-1].to_f`. Or see [the `monetize` gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/monetize) i.e. `Monetize.parse('£100.01').to_f`

Comment: I've set the currency default under the monetize gem to £ so this is probably it then. So, I should do event.price.string[1..-1].to_f then?

Comment: It's actually the money-rails gem I have installed. Do I need to install monetize also? It looks like the £ symbol is the issue as you describe above. I'd be grateful if you could clarify in a little more detail what the string[1..-1].to_f refers to and where I put this. Apologies if I seem a little slow - I'm a bit new to the money stuff.

Comment: please show your model code.

Comment: It's okay to ask. To change the string "$1.01" to the float `1.01` you can use `string[0..-1].to_f`, which removes the first character and converts what remains. `Monetize.parse("$1.01").to_f` does the same thing. The `money` gem used to provide the `parse` method but it has been moved to `monetize`. I don't see any reason why you would need to use a rails-specific gem for this i.e. `money-rails`.

Comment: My issue is where to put the string[0..-1].to_f method - do I place it in a method in the Booking model?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to strip your currency symbol

```
def total_amount
  quantity.to_i * strip_currency(event.price)
end

private

def strip_currency(amount = '')
  amount.to_s.gsub(/[^\d\.]/, '').to_f
end
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried to implement the above methods but I get an 'undefined method gsub' error. How do I rectify this? I feel I'm very close to getting the answer to my question. Hope you're able to respond.

Comment: check if the value you are getting for amount is string or convert it to string using `amount.to_s`

Comment: Should I use amount in the method as I don't have this stored in my booking or events table? Putting amount.to_s in the above method just brings a syntax error.

Comment: amount is your event.price which you are passing to this method

Comment: what value do you have in event.price

Comment: event.price is an integer so do I need to convert it to a string or a float to accept money?

Comment: strip_currency method will take care converting it to string replacing currency symbol and converting it back to float

Comment: The above now strips away the errors but I'm still not getting the amount showing - it still shows as 0.00(zero) when I click through to the payment page.

Comment: Should it be event.price_pennies to reflect the create method in the booking controller?

Comment: No that doesn't work either. I need to find an equation that will strip out the £ symbol. I wonder if the answer above works but I'm, not sure where I put string[0..-1].to_f in my MVC.

Comment: what you can do is just save float value in your @event.price and while displaying it in html join the currency symbol

Comment: That way you don't have to strip any symbols you can directly multiply it with whatever number you want

Answer (score -2):

If you are calling `booking.new` that means you are creating an instance of the class where as `self.` means you are using a class variable.

Remove the `self`.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong and I'm happy to be so. But, in the context of an instance method, I believe `self` resolves to the instance, not the class. If, in the context of an instance method, you want to get to class variable, you'd do something like `self.class.class_variable`. So, `quantity * event.price` **should** be the same as `self.quantity * self.event.price`. Again, apologies in advance if I've gotten this wrong.

Comment: You may be right but I think it has more to do with the responses above - the £ sign is rendering the output to 0(zero). I think this is the main issue.

Comment: @jvillian is completely correct; the only times that prepending `self.` to a method makes any difference are: 1) defining a class method, 2) calling a method on self which is shadowed by a local variable of the same name, 3) disambiguating a setter on self from a local variable assignment, and 4) calling private methods (which will fail when called with an explicit receiver, even if that receiver is self... except in the case of a private setter, for which an exception is made to avoid syntax ambiguity).